# Goal seek function in vba for a vector

Tags: excel, vba, function, vector

I have 3 vectors, let's call them A, B and C. What I want is to get A and B equal to eachother by changing C. Vector B has defined real number values, chosen by the user. While A is defined in a vba code and made dependent on C.

A = Blad1.Range(Cells(1, 153)),

B = Blad1.Range(Cells(3, 153)),

C = Blad1.Range(Cells(5, 153)).

I have tried the following code, however, it gives me an error. I would appreciate some help to resolving the issue.

```
For j = 1 To 150
    Blad1.Range(Cells(1, 3 + j - 1)).GoalSeek Goal:=Blad1.Range(Cells(3, 3 + j - 1)), changingCell:=Blad1.Range(Cells(5, 3 + j - 1))
Next j
```

Comment: Range(cells( 1, 3 + J -1 )) can be the problem. Either try Cells(1, 3 + j -1), or Range(Cells(1, 3 + j - 1), Cells(1, 3 + j -1))

Comment: @Blackcat that still gives an error

Comment: In the cell where A is the result there has to be an expression with an argument which refers to cell where C value is.

Comment: "vector" is not a term used in VBA, so it's difficult to figure out what you mean here - do you mean you have 3 arrays?  Of what dimensions?  "A is defined in a vba code and made dependent on C" - you would need to explain exactly how this occurs.